# The correct way to specify a sub query of a subquery using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
results = (from r in results 
where r.Buildings.Any(x=>x.StructuralElements.Any(s=>s.VALUE == Model.Bedrooms.ToString() && s.CATEGORY=="RM"))
select r);
```

I think I'm missing joins here.  But maybe they are implied?  The execution runs so long I can't do a watch to evaluate the generated query expression

Comment: "results = (from r in results " uh, show us the part of the query that came before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem in this query is this:

```
--@p1 = Models.Bedrooms.ToString()
--@p2 = "RM"
SELECT * FROM Results r WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT x.* FROM Results tr JOIN Buildings x ON tr.SomeID=x.SomeID WHERE tr.ID = r.ID AND EXISTS
        (SELECT s.* FROM StructuralElements s JOIN Buildings tx ON tx.OtherID = s.OtherID WHERE tx.ID=x.ID AND s.VALUE = @p1 AND s.Category = @p2))
```

Do you see why this would be bad? For every Result, you're running a subquery (which in itself is running a subquery). This is going to be an exponential increase in time/processing as you start adding things at the root levels (Results and Buildings) because of these nested subqueries. Your best bet is to use joins and get distinct `r` values after you're done. The SQL would like like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    r.* 
FROM
    Results r
    INNER JOIN Buildings x ON x.SomeID = r.SomeID
    INNER JOIN StructuralElements s ON s.OtherID = r.OtherID
WHERE
    s.VALUE = @p1 AND s.CATEGORY = @p2
```

The reason this will work is that when you join, if there are more than one to join back, it will duplicate the original row. The following illustration shows

```
IDs
R     X     S
1     -     -
Join X
1     1     -
1     2     -
1     3     -
Join S
1     1     1
1     1     2
1     2     5
1     2     6
```

Assuming `S=2` and `S=6` meet your criteria, then it will return (in `R,X,S` form) rows `1,1,2` and `1,2,6`. Getting just the distinct `r` in this case will only return `R=1`, which is what you're trying to accomplish. Using EF, the relationships already exist, so you don't need to do anything extra, just reference the columns you're trying to filter by:

```
results =  (from r in results
            from x in r.Buildings
            from s in x.StructuralElements
            where s.VALUE == Model.Bedrooms.ToString() && s.CATEGORY=="RM"
            select r).Distinct();
```

This is the SelectMany operator at play (which takes a collection and flattens out subcollections into a single collection).

Comment: You seem to have understood what I was asking.  I thought EF would handle alot of the grunt work.  let me test this and get back to you.

Comment: No problem. If the relationships weren't setup properly, then `SelectMany` would just end up being `FROM TableA, TableB` in query world. That's why EF (and L2S) handle the relationships for you, and will transform these references into joins. In general, I'd say try to stay away from `Any` when dealing with nested relationships (even in the SQL world).

Comment: I had no idea what I was doing. :\

Comment: Okay, this works. If I copy out the expression query into T-SQL it returns the expected number of rows, but in the application it returns 0 rows everytime.  Unrelated enough that I think I have to create another question.

Comment: Make sure that `results` actually has data before you start querying against it again. More than likely, that's what's happening. If you want fresh data, then just be sure you do `context.Set<Result>()` to get a reference to the `Result` entities.

Comment: Your right, because results is of type `IQueryable` to start, does this mean I must make two DB calls?  One to get the full set of data and a second to apply my `where` clauses? I was hoping to make one and only one final call to `.ToList()`

Comment: If it's IQueryable, then it should work. Ultimately, if you can do `from r in context.Results` it would work already. However, I'm wondering if you're already querying on some data in `results` so when you further compose the IQueryable it has no data. Right before you do that select, check if you get anything back from `results` by doing `int cnt = results.Count()` and see if it is greater than zero. If it is, run a quick DB query to verify that it actually has any data you're interested in.